# Firebase android shut down

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Google Firestore App is shutting down when I launch it but in Android Studio there are no errors.
Please Help.

```
private DocumentReference mDocFef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("news/1");
public TextView News1TextView;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mDocFef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                String news1TitleText = documentSnapshot.getString("Title");
                String news1ContentText = documentSnapshot.getString("Article");

                News1TextView.setText(news1TitleText + " " + news1ContentText);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView News1TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.news1Title);
    News1TextView.setText("123456789");
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.